# Python - select() does not catch broken socket

Tags: python, sockets, select

I am implementing a server in Python. I have been following the tutorial on [Doug Hellmann's blog](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/select/index.html):

I have a problem with `select()` not catching broken or closed pipe.

```
    # Create socket 
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Non blocking socket
    serversocket.setblocking(0)
    # Bind socket
    serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    # Socket listening
    serversocket.listen(5)

    # Sockets from which we expect to read
    inputs = [ serversocket ]
    # Sockets to which we expect to write
    outputs = [ ]

    resign = re.compile("resign")

    while inputs:
        print "Waiting for connection..."
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)

        for s in exceptional:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'handling exceptional condition for', s.getpeername()
            # Stop listening for input on the connection
            inputs.remove(s)
            s.close()


        for s in readable:
            # SERVER LISTENS TO CONNEXION
            if s is serversocket:

                if some_stuff_is_true:
                    connection, client_address = s.accept();
                    print 'New connection from ', client_address
                    connection.setblocking(0)
                    inputs.append(connection)


            # CLIENT READABLE
            else:
                data = s.recv(MAXLINE)
                #If socket has data to be read
                if data:
                    print data # Test if data correclty received
                    if resign.findall(data):
                        inputs.remove(s)
                        s.close()
```

When the client closes the socket normally, it is not catch by select, and when the client breaks the socket, it is not caught by `exceptional.

How to make this server robust to closed/broken sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a socket is cleanly closed by the remote end, then it will become "readable" for you. When you call `recv()`, you will get *zero* bytes back. Your code does not do anything in the `else:` clause of `if data:`. This is where you should put the code that reacts to a closed socket.

Comment: Is that different from a socket that is not sending data yet?

Comment: What about sockets that are not closed properly? Shouldn't be caught by 'exceptional'?

Comment: Sockets that are not sending data yet do not appear in "readable". Sockets that are not closed properly may show up in "exceptional" or may show up in "readable" and cause a Python exception when you call `recv()`. You will need to experiment and/or read the documentation for your OS to find out what happens in each specific situation.

Comment: So what happen with a socket that has been sending data, so that is in readable, but is suddenly disconnected?